# Using Chrome, window.open() action depends on shift key

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, event-handling

I'm pulling my hair out with this one as Chrome blatantly ignores the documented functionality of `window.open()`, sometimes opening in a new window rather than a new tab. There are many similar questions but none seem to have linked it to the use of the Shift key.

The code below opens the same image file in response to a click, ctrl+click, shift+click, or alt+click operation. The code is wanting to open them in a new tab, and all achieve this except for shift+click which ALWAYS opens a new window, no matter how I try and change my window.open call.

```
function clickHandler(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;

    if (!ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey && !ev.altKey) {    //click
        window.open('image.png','_blank');
        ev.preventDefault(); return;
    }
    if (ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey && !ev.altKey) { //ctrl+click
        window.open('image.png','_blank');
        ev.preventDefault(); return;
    }
    if (!ev.ctrlKey && ev.shiftKey && !ev.altKey) { //shift+click
        window.open('image.png','_blank');
        ev.preventDefault(); return;
    }
    if (!ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey && ev.altKey) { //alt+click
        window.open('image.png','_blank');
        ev.preventDefault(); return;
    }
 }


<div onclick="clickHandler(event);"> Click here </div>
```

Apologies for the itemised handling (i.e. each part ending in a return), but this was extracted from a much longer piece of code. My original code is handling click operations on SVG elements, but that appears to be unrelated. The configuration of which operation does what is under the control of the user and so I would like to make them all behave in a controlled manner, as per the documentation (if possible).

It looks like Google are imposing conventions on the user, and ignoring the fact that Chrome should be a general-purpose browser rather than a mere container for Google Search (sorry, paranoid rant over).

[Edited for clarification]
This is not specifically about the Chrome convention of Shift+Click on a link opening it in a new window. The end-users of this application are clicking on SVG elements, **not** links, and all of the modifiers (Shift, Cntl, etc) are available for them to configure functionality. However, the fact the Chrome browser is changing the functionality of an `window.open()` call based on some prior mouse operation is making a HUGE assumption that they've either clicked on a link, or are even aware that it's the equivalent of clicking on some link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the solution is to divorce the actions (in code) from the prior user operation, and the easiest way to do that is to throw them into a very short timer (less than a time-slice quantum but sufficient to prevent a race condition).

For instance:

```
if (!ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey && !ev.altKey) {    //click
    setTimeout (function() { window.open('image.png','_blank'); },20);
    ev.preventDefault(); return;
}
```

All four cases then perform identically and may be utilised by the application code without unwanted semantics.

I'm not sure how Chrome links these operation-action details as they don't seem to be in the event object, but this approach also solves another issue -- Ctrl+Click opening a new tab but not transferring focus, which differs from a normal click -- and possibly ones in other browsers (I'm thinking IE, here).